# Comparing dict values and popping the keys

Tags: python, dictionary, comparison

I have a big dictionary which simplified looks like this:

`my_dict = {'a': [-33.27, -2.12, 5.23], 'b': [-57.11, 9.82, -26.13], ...}`

*so keys are strings and values are lists of floats.*

What i want to do is to reduce it's size by running a criterion that finds and removes some redundant *key: value* pairs.

The criterion in **pseudo-code** is:

*for every key i, find whether a different key j exists in dict such that:*

- `value_of_key_i[0] > value_of_key_j[0] and`
- `value_of_key_i[1] > value_of_key_j[1] and`
- `abs(value_of_key_i[2]) < abs(value_of_key_j[2])`

What i wrote for the task is this:

```
to_remove = []
for ilcs, iloads in running_load.items():
    for jlcs, jloads in running_load.items():
        if iloads[0] > jloads[0] and iloads[1] > jloads[1] and abs(iloads[2]) < abs(jloads[2]):
            # print(iloads, jloads)
            to_remove.append(ilcs)
            break

for i in to_remove:
    running_load.pop(i)
```

which does work, but explicitly traversing the dict twice and the necessary additional for-loop for the popping feels inefficient..

Is there a better way? Would it be more efficient to do this with generators and, let's say, `any()`?

P.S: another problem with my approach is that it cannot test for equality since at some point the values are going to be tested against themselves (and yes one could check for that and `continue` but...)

Comment: You might benefit from sorting `load.items()` on those values so you can avoid looking at lists that you know don't meet your criteria

Comment: Good point but i actually need them to be in that order. i cannot sort the values. But maybe i could use an `ordereddict`, order it by let's say `values[0]` and search only the slice infront of the current key..

Comment: what order do you want the values back in?  There's no guarantee that they will be the same order coming out of the dictionary as they were going in.

Comment: I think you are using the term _values_ rather loosely. You probably mean _items_ or _entries_. _values_ are the _values_ from the `key: value` pairs (the lists in my example)

Comment: Sorry if I was confusing.  What i meant was that you could do something like `sorted(running_load.items(), key=...)` where your key function orders the entries based on the criteria you have for your values.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a list of elements to remove, you could create a new dictionary and add in it only the elements that will be kept.

I don't really see a way to reduce the O(n^2) complexity in the initial phase (compare every element against every other element), but as mentioned above sorting will help some.

Also, I think you will generate two different lists with identical content from the items in dictionary (one list in each for). This shouldn't count too much compared to "compare every item to every other item", but it still helps.

Answer (score 0):

So along the initial and probably most obvious solution (algo1) i wrote a second one (algo2) that:

- creates a list of tuples from the dict.
- orders it (thus reducing comparisons to just 2).
- slices it (thus reducing comparisons from n^2 to (n^2+n)/2 -> *the bigger the n, the bigger the advantage*)
- and pops in the same loop.

---

```
def algo1(a_dict):
    to_remove = []
    for ilcs, iloads in a_dict.items():
        for jlcs, jloads in a_dict.items():
            if iloads[0] > jloads[0] and iloads[1] > jloads[1] and abs(iloads[2]) < abs(jloads[2]):
                # print(iloads, jloads)
                to_remove.append(ilcs)
                break
    for i in to_remove:
        a_dict.pop(i)
    return a_dict

def algo2(a_dict):
    ordered_list_view = sorted(a_dict.items(), key=lambda t: abs(t[1][2]))
    for i, ikv in enumerate(ordered_list_view):
        forward_slice = ordered_list_view[i:]
        for j, jkv in enumerate(forward_slice):
            if all(ikv[1][j] > jkv[1][j] for j in range(2)):
                print(ikv[1], jkv[1])
                a_dict.pop(ikv[0])
                break
    return a_dict
```

I timed them too but to my surprise, algo1 was still faster. Marginally, but still..